# Display Div1 for x sec then hide and display hidden Div2

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I am trying to display div1 for 3 sec then hide and display div2. Please note I am not an expert Javascript developer. However, I have managed, by Googling and copy & paste, to display and hide div1.

I am not able to display div2 when div1 hides. Below is the code....

```
<div id="Div2" style="display:none">
php code here
</div>

<div id="Div1" style="display:none"><img id="myImage" src="ajax-loader.gif"></div><br>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function show() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
    setTimeout("hide()", 3000);  // 3 seconds
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
}

show();
function show2() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv1").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the answer in jQuery or plain javascript?

Comment: There's no jQuery code here, it's all plain Javascript. I guess not knowing the difference is part of not being an expert.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. such a silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `show2()` after you hide `Div1`. Also, you had the wrong IDs in your functions.

```js
function show() {
    document.getElementById("Div1").style.display="block";
    setTimeout("hide()", 3000);  // 3 seconds
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("Div1").style.display="none";
    show2();
}

show();
function show2() {
    document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="block";
}
```

```html
<div id="Div2" style="display:none">
php code here
</div>

<div id="Div1" style="display:none"><img id="myImage" src="ajax-loader.gif"></div><br>
```

Comment: tried, not working. i need to display div1 for 3 sec (disappeared after 3 secs) and then display div2 (div2 remains hidden for 3 secs). your solution made div1 disappear and div2 appear.

Answer (score -1):

You gave a String to setTimeout

```
setTimeout("hide()", 3000);  // 3 seconds
```

but it expects a function:

```
setTimeout(hide, 3000);  // 3 seconds
```

Comment: i did not understand.

Comment: If you give it a string, it executes it using `eval()`.